# Validating XML which has '& 'against XSD throws "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference"

Tags: java, xml, xsd, sax

I have a xml which contains '&' in the content, and i am trying to validate the xml aganist the xsd using the following code

`SchemaFactory factory = 
            SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));`

the code works fine when XML doesnt has a '&',

but throws this error

"The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference" when '&' is included.

any suggestions to work around this are gladly accepted.
thanks in advance!! :)

EDIT:
i Have been trying to use &amp, we have to use `&amp;`
solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the character `&` in the text in an XML document, it must be written as [the character entity `&amp;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) or be inside a [`CDATA` section](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect).

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape special characters like &.

& is used to represent other special character like <: &lt;

replace & with &amp;

Answer (score 0):

The '&' is illegal in XML content. Are you allowed to change the XML? You could wrap your problematic content with a [CDATA section](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)